# Prevent the user from making a GET request to a page

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, web.xml

I am sorry if my question does not make any sense. So here is what I have: 2 pages, `A.jsf` and `B.jsf`. When I press a button in `A.jsf`, the code set the value of an `object` and redirect to `B.jsf`. Contain of `B.jsf` will depend on which object I set in `A.jsf` (which depend on which button I click). Therefore, I dont want to allow the user to type this on the web browser

http://myhost:myport/myproject/B.jsf

and get directly to `B.jsf`. So, no GET request to `B.jsf`, only POST. And if I see GET request to `B.jsf`, I redirect to `A.jsf`. I feel like the solution is inside `web.xml`.
btw, I am using Netbean 6.8 and java EE 6

**EDIT**
Here is the solution. Thanks to BalusC
`MyFilter.java`

```
package org.xdrawings.filter;

public class MyFilter implements Filter{

    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    public void destroy(){}

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig){
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException{
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if("GET".equals(req.getMethod()) && "/B.jsf".equals(req.getServletPath())){
            res.sendRedirect("A.jsf");
        }else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

then in my `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.xdrawings.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>My Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

`All credits go to BalusC`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as you guessed, this *can* be controlled from in the `web.xml`. You need to declare a `security-constraint` on an `url-pattern` of `/b.jsf` with `http-method` of `GET`, along with an empty `auth-constraint`.

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Prevent GET requests on the b.jsf file</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>The b.jsf file</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/b.jsf</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

This however shows a [HTTP 403 error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4). This doesn't (and can't) redirect to `a.jsf` (at least, not without supplying a custom 403 error page with the necessary checks, but that's plain ugly). If the redirect is mandatory, other solutions are available:

1. In the constructor of the request scoped bean associated with `b.jsf` check for postback by [`ResponseStateManager#isPostback()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/render/ResponseStateManager.html#isPostback%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) and then redirect accordingly using [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

   ```
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   if (!context.getRenderKit().getResponseStateManager().isPostback(context)) {
       context.getExternalContext().redirect("a.jsf");
   }
   ```

   If you're already on JSF 2.0, you can also use the convenience method [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) instead, which is less typing.
2. Or as a more high-level approach, create a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which does exactly the task. The requested page and the HTTP method can be obtained by [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) and [`getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) respectively and the redirect can be done using [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

   ```
   HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
   HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
   if ("GET".equals(req.getMethod()) && "/b.jsf".equals(req.getServletPath())) {
      res.sendRedirect("a.jsf");
   } else {
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   ```

   This can be more easily extended for future methods and pages which you can configure as under each `init-param` of the `Filter` in `web.xml`.

Comment: It amazes me how much you know about Web development. Your first method work great. However, I kind of want to learn the second method as well, since I always heard about people creating Filter but not sure what it is about. So it seem like you are creating a custom `Filter` here, and tell the project to use that filter via `web.xml`, correct? Let me try it out and I get back to you. Thank you very much man

Comment: I implement your second method, but I have couple questions, can u look at my updated post to see my implementation.

Comment: The filter could be mapped on an `<url-pattern>` of `/*`, or more specific `*.jsf`, or even more specific the `/b.jsf` (and then remove the unnecessary check in the `if` block). The `<init-param>` is optional. If you define any, it'll be available by [`FilterConfig#getInitParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/FilterConfig.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) inside `init()` method which you can then assign as instance variable and use it further in `doFilter()` logic. E.g. a commaseparated string of pagenames and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I successfully got it. But I think `res.sendRedirect("/a.jsf");` is actually `res.sendRedirect("a.jsf");`

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with making `B.jsf` check for the value set in `A.jsf`, and issue a redirect if it's not present?